# PHP-FPM and PHP execution yields different results

Tags: linux, php, docker, php-fpm

I have used a docker container with the embedded `php` server for development. Now we are creating a test environment and we wanted to use `php-fpm`. Everything went fine and the whole thing works as expected, with one difference - ImageMagick.

The same command, executed from `php` embedded server and `php-fpm` yields different results:

When converting images using the embedded server it works just fine, but when using `php-fpm`, I get:

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: no images defined `-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

It's really frustrating because it's the same container, the same `php` installation, the same php.ini.

EDIT:
Command used:

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/convert -thumbnail "50x50+0+0" /app/assets/uploads/super_e55d4fbf182b582f5bb1_bottle05.png -");
```

EDIT2:
I have tried executing something "simple", and here's the output:

```
‌‌shell_exec("/usr/bin/identify");
‌Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org[...]

‌‌shell_exec("ls /app/assets/uploads/super_e55d4fbf182b582f5bb1_bottle05.png");
/app/assets/uploads/super_e55d4fbf182b582f5bb1_bottle05.png

‌‌shell_exec("/usr/bin/identify /app/assets/uploads/super_e55d4fbf182b582f5bb1_bottle05.png");
‌null
```

EDIT3:

```
‌‌shell_exec("/usr/bin/identify /app/assets/uploads/super_e55d4fbf182b582f5bb1_bottle05.png 2>&1");
‌identify-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
```

while executed directly in shell:

```
/usr/bin/identify /app/assets/uploads/super_e55d4fbf182b582f5bb1_bottle05.png 2>&1
/app/assets/uploads/super_e55d4fbf182b582f5bb1_bottle05.png PNG 520x1020 520x1020+0+0 8-bit sRGB 319KB 0.010u 0:00.009
```

Comment: What are you executing to get that error?

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the notification. I have updated the question.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP's Imagick class directly, instead of calling out to the shell? This code smells to high heaven...

Comment: According to what we saw in the docs, in order to use the HEIC/HEIF conversions we have to use the latest imagick and it does not support that in the php module. So we do use a PHP library we have installed through composer which in turn uses the convert directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the environment variables to correct values to make it work through `shell_exec()`. Those variables were not set in shell.

```
MAGICK_HOME
MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH
MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH
```

In my case:

```
  MAGICK_HOME=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7/
  MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH=/etc/ImageMagick/
  MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7/modules-Q16/coders
```

I have made sure that my container will always get this specific version of image magick not to be surprised in the future, in my case:

```
RUN apt-get install -y imagemagick=8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u5
```